# High Fastly CDN Usage

Tags: magento2.4, cdn, fastly

Hope all doing well, I am working on Magento 2.4.4 E.C.E Cloud Instance, Using Fastly as a CDN, What i am facing is we are having very high cdn consumption, does any body have faced this issue and know how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance